# Slim, Postman and AngularJs : $app->request->getBody() vs $app->request->post()

Tags: angularjs, rest, slim, postman

I'm a beginner. I've written a test application made of an AngularJs GUI on the client side and a PHP API on the server side.

This is the angular service handling the requests

```
myApp.factory('Book', ['$resource', 'API_URL', function($resource, API_URL){

    return $resource(API_URL + '/books/:bookId', {bookId: '@bookId'}, {
        get: { method: 'GET', isArray:true },
        update: { method: 'PUT'},
        save: { method: 'POST'},
        delete: {method:'DELETE'},
    });

}]);
```

When I submit a book from the Angular app I can catch the POST in Slim by using

```
$post_a = json_decode($app->request->getBody());
//$post_b = $app->request->post(); //this would be empty
```

When I use Postman and I perform a POST I can catch the POST in Slim by using

```
//$post_a = json_decode($app->request->getBody()); // this would be empty
$post_b = $app->request->post();
```

I don't get why there is this difference. Could you please explain?

Am I not meant to catch the post just with $app->request->post(); in both the cases? Why the post coming from Angular can be caught only with $app->request->getBody()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$app->request->post()` method retrieves key/value data submitted in a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request. If the request uses a different content-type (e.g. `application/json`), you can retrieve the raw request body with the `$app->request->getBody()` method and decode it as necessary. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Ha! I see, thank you! My point was also to understand how to test the endpoint with Postman and now I see that I've to set the Header Content-Type to "application/json" then the body has to be "Raw" and has to contain a json like {"title":"new title"} and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

You could still use

> $post_b = $app->request->post()

in Slim.

As long as you call this REST service from html form (AngularJS) by passing the data as form value formatted instead of as JSON.
If in AngularJS you have the data in JSON format, you have to translate it first into form. Below is the example how to invoke this REST service:

```js
Object.toparams = function ObjecttoParams(obj) {
    var p = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        p.push(key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
    }
    return p.join('&');
};

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: Object.toparams(myobject),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
```

myobject is the data in JSON format that is going to be created

Answer (score -1):

**Thanks Josh..Your answers works for me.**

Steps to follow:

1.You need to send request in json format under raw tab like this:

```
{"username":"admin","password":"admin"}
```

2.You need to set `Content-Type`  to `application/json` in the headers.

That's it and it will work.